# How to configure eth0 manually?

Tags: networking

How to manually configure `eth0` in Ubuntu?
I don't have any DHCP server. Do I need IP address when I am just going to capture packets?

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure what you exactly mean by your question. The real manual method has been described above, but since you write you don't have DHCP, I think you rather would like to know what to do to give your box a static IP address and assign this IP address at boot time automatically. Well, here is how:

There should be a file `/etc/network/interfaces`. This file is read by the Ubuntu boot scripts which in turn configure the network according to that file. If you would like to know what should / could go into that file, then please type "[man interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/interfaces.5.html)".

For example, my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this (comments are cut out):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.20.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.20.0
        broadcast 192.168.20.255
        gateway 192.168.20.250
```

The first two lines are standard and may already look similar on your box. You may be interested especially in the rest of the file: These lines define a static network configuration to eth0 (without DHCP), and this static configuration gets active automatically on every boot.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try this as well:

1. `sudo -H gedit /etc/network/interfaces`
2. Edit the eth0

   ```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
   ```
3. Save and Exit
4. Run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need IP address for capturing packets in promiscuous mode (when you want to capture all traffic, not just traffic destined to your computer). You can put that interface up using command

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

This do not assign IPv4 address to interface (IPv6 local-link address is automatically assigned, if you have IPv6 enabled).

Comment: with the new `ip` use `ip link set eth0 up` instead

Answer (score -1):

```
ifconfig
ifconfig etho
ifconfig ehto 192.168.3.40 netmask 255.255.255.0
route -n
```

or

```
ip route show
then 
name for DNS
nameserver 127.0.11
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: the abover answer just configuration for ip address