# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Won't Connect to the School's Wired Network

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, ethernet, wired

My computer is connected to the school's network via an Ethernet cable, but ubuntu won't recognize the network.  It will scan the network for about 30 seconds and then a small error window pops up saying "Network disconnected, You are now offline".

I have been trying to fix the issue for almost 3 days now; I even re-installed Ubuntu from my bootable USB.  This was a scratch install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via a bootable usb (which was created on my Macbook pro after I converted the .iso to a .img file) on a new computer that I just recently built.  I already contacted my school's IT department, and my MAC address is registered with them.  However, I am the only student running linux on the entire campus and they are unable to give me further support.  I have researched the forums extensively and have tried various solutions, but none seem to work.  I was advised by the IT department to leave my internet connection for IPv4 on automatic DHCP, rather than setting it to manual and copying the information from my laptop.  Additionally I tried using a friends USB wireless adapter (a Netgear Wireless N-300), but Ubuntu didn't recognize the device as a wireless adapter.  As a result, wireless does not appear to be a viable backup solution.

When my IPv4 is set to automatic (as recommended by my IT department) my terminal `ifconfig` is

```
Eth0 Link encamp:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:45:0d:bc:b5
     inet6 addr: fe80:76d4:35ff:fe0d:bcb5/64 Scope:Link
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 METRIC:1
     RX packets:389 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
     RX bytes:39214 (39.2 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo   Link encap: Local Loopback
     inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
     inet6 addr:  ::1/128 Scope:Host
     UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU: 65536 Metric:1
     RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets 16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
     RX bytes:1312 (1.3 KB)  TX bytes: 1312 (1.3 KB)
```

When my IPv4 is set to manual and is copied from my MacBook Pro's internet configuration, my `ifconfig` is:

```
will@Anarch:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:0d:bc:b5  
      inet addr:138.234.212.246  Bcast:138.234.223.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::76d4:35ff:fe0d:bcb5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:22060 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:3371 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2659497 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:461 (461.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:4597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:404944 (404.9 KB)  TX bytes:404944 (404.9 KB)
```

As seen in the comments below this question, here are the results for the `ipshow` command when IPv4 is set to automatic:

`ip link show 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000 link/ether 74:d4:35:0d:bc:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Here is my `nm-tool` for the automatic IPv4 setup:

```
will@Anarch:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connecting

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 2] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connecting (getting IP configuration)
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        74:D4:35:0D:BC:B5

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on
```

Here is my nm-tool for the manual IPv4 configuration:

```
will@Anarch:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        74:D4:35:0D:BC:B5

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         138.234.212.246
    Prefix:          20 (255.255.240.0)
    Gateway:         138.234.208.1

    DNS:             138.234.4.54
    DNS:             138.234.196.47
    DNS:             138.234.4.158
```

This is the Ping to google's server (Ip: 8.8.8.8) using Manual network settings:

```
will@Anarch:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Here is a short list of failed solutions that I have already tried from other forum posts:

- manually setting up my IPv4 based off of the information from my laptop's (A MacBook Pro) network connections
- registering my MAC address with the campus
- Resetting the ethernet by turning the card off and on in the Bios setup
- Deleting and creating the network connection in the Network Connection’s window
- Using `echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`
- And other's that I can't call to mind at the moment

I'm done with classes for the day, so if anyone needs any more information please let me know.  I will continue to troubleshoot for the rest of the day, so any help is greatly appreciated.

*P.S.* Would it be advisable to try to install a different distro of Linux and see if it can connect to the network?

Thank you,
William

Comment: Why do you copy the ifconfig stuff by hand instead of using Ctrl+Shift+C?

Comment: Please add the output of 'ip link show'

Comment: Also, a list of some of the things you've tried over the last 3 days would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to connect to Internet when you boot from the Live-usb? Also, are you able to connect to Internet somewhere else? It may be a local issue.

Comment: 1) because I couldn't find my extra usb drive (Im posting from my mac because my pc can't connect to the internet.)

Comment: 2) Sure give me a few minutes.

Comment: 3) I tried reseting the dhclient via the terminal command, inserting the extra lines into the nano version of the networkconfig file (mentioned in quite a few forum posts), deleting and creating the wired connection, and I tried resetting the ethernet by turning my card off and on.  I have tried the above multiple times with various terminal commands, and none seem to take.

Comment: 4) I am not able to connect to the internet from a live usb boot, and Yes i, as well as my entire dorm floor, can connect to the internet via wired or wireless connections with other computers.  However, I am the only one with a ubuntu os

Comment: I meant, can *your* computer connect to Internet somewhere else, such as a coffee shop or something? I'm trying to figure which interface is the problem

Comment: 1. Assuming you dual-boot with Windows, can you connect via Windows? If you can't, your motherboard is probably faulty, and there isn't much you can do about it (since ethernet is usually built in the motherboard, unlike wireless cards)

Comment: 2. Given that you have hardware confirmation, can you try connecting in a coffee shop? Althought that wouldn't confirm for the ethernet cable, it would help determin where the problem is. If you can connect at Coffee shop, then it is a Ubuntu-SchoolNetwork problem. If you can't connect at Coffee shop, then it is more likely to be Ubuntu-hardware problem.

Comment: I'm not dual booting, I am running Ubuntu as the only OS.  Also, It's a computer tower with a brand new gigabyte motherboard, so I don't think that it is a hardware issue.  Also since it is a tower, I cannot bring it to a coffee shop to test its connectivity.

Comment: `ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:d4:35:0d:bc:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

Comment: I believe this could be a Ubuntu-hardware issue, as suggested by morphheus.  Here is a link to the motherboard I am using from newegg.com:http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128627

Also, after trying multiple fixes that were recommended by other forum posts, I decided to try to reinstall the Ubuntu kernel, so as of right now it is a 100% scratch install that is ready for new modifications.

Comment: Usually "Network disconnected, You are now offline" means your network detected but not connected. Does your school network require user name and password ?

Comment: yes it does require my username and password, but I am unable to locate the page.  The page for login is usually in a browser window, however my browser (the pre-installed firefox) fails to connect to the internet or my schools website page.

Comment: @Prinz Is there a way to enter the username and password without visiting the school's page?

Comment: Try : from network manager -> dsl (or wired ->802.1 security) -> create new. Enter your user name and password there. Connect using the new created setting. Also it is a good thing to explain step by step procedure on how other students connect using Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixed it.  It turns out that 12.04 LTS won't connect to the internet, I don't know why but it just won't.  Anyway, I installed a 32-bit old version of Ubuntu, and its working swimmingly.  My advice to anyone with a similar issue is to swallow your pride, and install an older version of the OS.  It will save you A TON of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please restart your network manager using terminal.

To open terminal press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> & then enter below command;

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

you'll be prompted for root password, enter the password (you won't see what you're typing, don't worry its just normal) & you'll see something like below;

```
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 3682
```

Once done please wait for few seconds until the network manager loads. Once done, you'll see the network notification panel which is trying to connect to any available network source. While it does it part, try to ping you localhost to see whether your NIC is functioning. To do so, try below on the same terminal;

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
```

If you see something like above which means your NIC is functioning.. if not please edit your question and post the output of what you've received.

Comment: My NIC is functioning, however I am still unable to connect to a network.  The Network manager is still searching for the connection, as it does every time I try to connect to the wired connection 1.

Comment: well if it functions which means you should be able to connect as the MAC address will remain the same even you use windows or linux. have you tried assigning IP's manually despite the DHCP just to check whether you're able to connect?

Comment: I just entered everything in manually, and I was able to establish a network connection.  However, I still am unable to connect to the internet in my browser.  Also, even though I just did it, the school's IT department advised me not to enter the information manually.

Comment: Are they using any proxy servers?? once you connected manually have you tried pinging any websites to check whether its accessible? (If they're using proxy servers, probably that's another reason for browsing issue even though you connected to network). Have you by any-chance questioned them as to why not use manual settings (just to acknowledge yourself)?

Comment: I don't believe they are using proxy servers, and I just tried to ping google (ip address: 8.8.8.8).  Here are the results of `ping 8.8.8.8`:
`will@Anarch:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 138.234.212.246 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable`

I am going to call the IT department right now to question it.  I will edit this comment when I finish the call

Comment: The IT department is busy as of right now, so I should expect a call back within 5-10 minutes.  I double checked the network settings on my mac, and every proxy is turned off for my wifi.

Comment: type `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.back` with root in order to back up the file and then type `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`, replace `nameserver 127.0.0.1` with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and in a new line below `nameserver 8.8.4.4`. once done, hit `CTRL+O` to write file, enter to save & hit `CTRL+X` to exit. once done check browsing again

Comment: Browser still can't find the server.  Here is a copy of the nano file exactly as I saved it:
    `# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
    #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE      OVERWRITTEN
    nameserver 8.8.8.8
    search ms.gettysburg.edu`

Comment: It seems that the entire IT department is out sick today.  Do you have anymore possible solutions?

Comment: why is there a search under the output of your `resolv.conf`?? can you post the output of the once again. use `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: That was for the manual setup, where I entered it as the search because that's how it is under my laptop's network configuration. The automatic setup comes back as `name server 127.0.0.1`, however the automatic can't connect to the network at all.

Comment: Yes it should as the resolv.conf doesn't store dns but it should work until you reboot. Well, this may be an odd question but have you check the ETH cable whether its a straight-through or a cross-over?? did you use the same cable to connect internet before?? I mean the same cable itself?

Comment: It is a straight through Ethernet cable that was provided by my school's IT department.  I have used it multiple times for connecting my MacBook Pro to the internet here.

Comment: looks strange to me and the comments are been dragging as I couldn't move this to a chat due lower points you have. Nevertheless, when you add IP's manually what attributes did you add into the network and were you able to ping internal networks?? Also try to add it once again via terminal by following only `IP Addressing` part from here > https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html .. do it until the `ip addr flush eth0` command & let me know again

Comment: I had an error when trying to add a route:

`will@Anarch:~$ sudo route add default gw  138.234.208.1 eth0
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`

Comment: try this instead, `/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 1.1.1.1 eth0` .. replace the 1.1.1.1 with your proper gateway... if it didn't work, may I see an output for interfaces.. try `cat /etc/network/interfaces` .. also try

Comment: command was not found for the added route.  Here is the output for the network interfaces: `sudo: /sbin/route/add: command not found
will@Anarch:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

Comment: type `sudo ifdown eth0` & type `nano /etc/network/interfaces`.. and add the part which starts with `auto eth0` from here > http://askubuntu.com/a/31046/179042 .. replace all the IPs with your network range. once done up the network using `sudo ifup eth0`.. see whether it works..

Comment: Will do, but I am being forced to take an hour break by my roommate.  I'll post the results when I get back.

Comment: Everything worked, but I still can't connect to the network on the auto settings or the internet on the manual settings.

Comment: Pretty strange even after attempting a lot of things it still didn't connect. I'm sorry I'm lost & I've given all necessary things that I could come up with. Try to boot Ubuntu with a live CD or a Live bootable USB just to check the connectivity.

Comment: I've done that multiple times now, and I have tried different distros just to see if it was a ubuntu error, but it isn't.  I'm going to take a ubuntu USB and run it at the IT department, because I am almost positive it's a fault with my school's network.

Comment: Yes! It should be something to do with the networking side I assume. Let us know how it goes. :)