# Can't connect to internet on minimal Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ubuntu-minimal

I just installed minimal Ubuntu to a pendrive. I did this by using VirtualBox, connecting the pendrive to it and installing to it. I did not install any additional software. But when I booted to it I can't access the internet.

typing `ifconfig -a` shows I don't have  `eth0` but instead a `p3p1`.

And `/etc/network/interfaces` initially had `eth0` set to `auto` but I changed that to `p3p1` and that did not help. I don't have network manager installed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure eth0 manually?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31023/how-to-configure-eth0-manually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to this myself:

first:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

then make its contents as:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p3p1
iface p3p1 inet dhcp
```

save and close nano.

and finally:

```
sudo ifdown p3p1 && sudo ifup -v p3p1
```

You should have gotten internet back. Now install network-manager if you don't want to do this again after reboot.